# Deep copy Observable Collection on Collection Changed event

Tags: c#, observablecollection

Here's what I have right now:

```
public ObservableCollection<ClientInfo> Clone(ObservableCollection<ClientInfo> clone)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(ms, clone);
    ms.Position = 0;
    object obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);
    ms.Close();
    return obj as ObservableCollection<ClientInfo>;
}

void ItemList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<ClientInfo> list = sender as ObservableCollection<ClientInfo>;

    ItemList = Clone(list);
    //MessageBox.Show("Event: CollectionChanged");
}
```

In the debugger `sender` contains my ObservableCollection, I can see all the variables and they seem right but for some reason casting it to ObservableCollection manually seems to null it out because I get `Argument Null Exception` and in the debugger `list` is indeed null. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you see the type of the sender in the debugger? Perhaps you can print the type out in the console and it might not be an ObservableCollection?

Comment: Yes, the type of the sender is ObservableCollection<ClientInfo>. Might it have something to do with sender being in another class?

Comment: sender being in another class shouldnt be a problem as you are still able to see it in the debugger. Is your code multithreaded or something like that and the sender you see is different than the ArgumentNullException you get? I believe you are getting ArgumentNullException in bf.Serialize?

Comment: The class is an asynchronous socket class I'm trying to code, but right now it doesn't contain any multithreading code. The ArgumentNullException indeed originates from `bf.Serialize`, but list is becoming null as soon as I cast sender to it (first line of event function). Call stack is like this: Button click on MainForm to add client to ObservableCollection in socket class, which triggers an event that calls `ItemList_CollectionChanged` function in MainWindow class.

Comment: Use a direct cast instead of using as. `list = (ObservableCollection<ClientInfo>)sender;` then copy the exception details to the question